# How to present parameters and their contents for each attribute

Tags: arcgis-server, attribute-table, excel

I have a table of data and I would like to know how I can use this data for a cartographic presentation and a publication on a geoportal as well as a map service.

The data represents measuring stations and for each measuring station, different parameters (130 parameters) have been measured, such as PH, turbidity, water temperature, calcium-ca ....

All the parameters are stored in the same excel file, but by sheet and for each parameter we have a table that contains: average, maximum, detections ....

I exported these stations on ArcMap and I made roles with Relationship Classes for each parameters (just for 20 parameters), witch mean one clicks with "identify" on a station, we can consult the list of parameters, as well as the contents of each parameter for this selected station.

The problem now is that these relationships can’t appear after a publication of this map like a mapserver.

What can you propose to me? Anyone have another idea of the presentation and consultation of this data as much as map service.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An ArcGIS Server Feature Service allows you to query for related records:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Query_Related_Records/02r300000115000000/

1) When you create your map service make sure you enable the "Feature Access" capability

2) You will have to add functionality to take advantage of the REST API's "Query Related Records" function (the link above).